My character doesnt move after enabling with Hold interaction
I have a problem with InputActions
I have an Actions MoveX that has binding 1D Axis with hold interaction
In my game are 4 characters in the scene
but only one is active and you can switch between tham
So the problem is when i disable my character and then enable it while my button D or A is still active my character stops and to move i need to press this button again
And i have no idea how to fix this (
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class CharacterController : MonoBehaviour
{
    private StateManager stateManager;
    [SerializeField] private string name;

    private CharacterMovement movement;
    private CharacterJump jump;

    public Animator anim;
    public Rigidbody2D rb;
    private SpriteRenderer spriteRenderer;

    private InputActions controls;

    public float horizontal;

    public bool flipOnMove;

    public bool isGround;
   
    void Awake()
    {
        controls = new InputActions();

        controls.Main.MoveX.performed += ctx => 
        {
            horizontal = ctx.ReadValue<float>();
        };

        controls.Main.MoveX.canceled += ctx =>
        {
            horizontal = 0;
        };

        controls.Main.Jump.started += ctx => JumpStart();
        controls.Main.Jump.canceled += ctx => JumpEnd();

        stateManager = FindObjectOfType<StateManager>();

        anim = GetComponent<Animator>();
        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
        spriteRenderer = GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>();

        movement = GetComponent<CharacterMovement>();
        jump = GetComponent<CharacterJump>();
        
    }

    void Update()
    {
        if(flipOnMove)
        {
            switch(horizontal)
            {
                case -1:
                    spriteRenderer.flipX = true;
                    break;
                case 1:
                    spriteRenderer.flipX = false;
                    break;
            }
        }
    }

    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        Move(horizontal);
    }

    void OnEnable()
    {
        controls.Enable();

        stateManager.currentGameObject = gameObject;
        stateManager.currentStatesName = name;

        if(stateManager.lastGameObjectTs != null) // зберігання позиції
        {
            gameObject.transform.position = stateManager.lastGameObjectTs.position;
            if(name == "Human") // Якщо людина то спавнити вище
                gameObject.transform.position += new Vector3(0f,0.4f,0f);
            gameObject.transform.rotation = stateManager.lastGameObjectTs.rotation;
        }

        if(stateManager.lastGameObjectRb != null) // Зберігання фізики
        {
            Rigidbody2D rb = gameObject.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
            rb.velocity = stateManager.lastGameObjectRb;
        }

        
    }

    void OnDisable()
    {
        controls.Disable();
    }

    public void Move(float direction)
    {
        if(movement != null)
        {
            movement.Move(direction);
        }
    }

    public void JumpStart()
    {
        if(jump != null)
        {
            jump.Jump();
        }
    }

    public void JumpEnd()
    {
        if(jump !=  null)
        {
            jump.StopJumpAnim();
        }
    }
}


I've tried to check button press in Update method but it still doesnt work
Also if i delete , controls.Disable() in OnDisable() i will work fine
but i will have a lot of errors in the console so i think its not the right way

I'd say this is pretty much an issue of the OnDisable .. you should probably rather unsubscribe the callbacks or ensure they are ignored while the object is disabled .. fizzling with the enabling of the actions doesn't seem to be right as you always want them to be enabled ... Just handled by different character instances

okey , so i just deleted controls.Enable and Disable and now its working perfectly
Thank you very much

Infact you could even make most of things static and only differ between which instance should currently receive the callbacks

I deleted controls.Enable() and controls.Disable() and now it's working.
